# Oracle - Sequencing in the table based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table customer_order with the columns

```
ORD_ID, AI_LN, ITEM
```

The data is like

```
A100 null 001232
A100 null 108632
A100 null 501632
A200 null 301632
A200 null 601732
```

I need to number AI_LN based on order, so it becomes

```
A100 0 001232
A100 1 108632
A100 2 501632
A200 0 301632
A200 1 601732
```

How to do that ? Would it be one via PLSQL block?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select the ai_ln as given, you can use window function in select:

```
select ord_id,
    row_number() over (
        partition by ord_id order by item
        ) - 1 as ai_ln,
    item
from your_table;
```

If you want to update the table with it, you can use it in a merge statement.

```
merge into your_table t
using (
    select ord_id,
        row_number() over (
            partition by ord_id order by item
            ) - 1 as ai_ln,
        item
    from your_table
    ) s
    on (s.rowid = t.rowid)
when matched
    then
        update
        set t.ai_ln = s.ai_ln;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use PL/SQL, this can be done in SQL using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SELECT ORD_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ORD_ID
                           ORDER BY ITEM ) -- or ORDER BY ROWNUM
         AS ai_ln,
       ITEM
FROM   customer_order;
```

If you want to update the table then:

```
UPDATE customer_table c
SET ai_ln = (
  SELECT rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_id
                               ORDER BY item )
             AS rn
    FROM   customer_table
  ) r
  WHERE c.ROWID = r.ROWID
);
```

Or `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO customer_table dst
USING ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ord_id
                                   ORDER BY item ) AS rn
        FROM   customer_table ) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET ai_ln = src.rn;
```

Comment: Correct me if I wrong , but updating table with self correlated query, it is a expensive, isn't it? I think it will be more efficient doing in loop.

Comment: @Seyran If you are talking about a PL/SQL loop  then context switching will be more expesive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` analytic function:

```
select ORD_ID
     , row_number() over(partition by ORD_ID order by ITEM ) -1 as AI_LN
     , ITEM
  from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `row_number()`:

```
update t
    set ai_ln = (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.ord_id = t.ord_id and t2.item <= t.item);
```

You would want to use this under the following circumstances:

- You have an index on `(ord_id, item)`.
- There are no duplicate items for an order.
- The largest order has a limited number of items (say a few dozen).